# How to fetch data from a REST API by using an API-Token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, jira

I'm trying to fetch data from the Jira Rest API in my React application by using the Axios library for http requests. An API token is necessary, in order to access data via the Jira API. I generated an API token in my Jira account settings, but I can't figure out, how to include it in my http request to gain access.

This is the endpoint provided by the Jira documentation for getting an issue from the Jira board:

```
curl -u admin:admin http://localhost:8080/jira/rest/api/2/issue/TEST-10 | python -mjson.tool
```

This is the React state hook for setting the data to the fetched data:

```
    const [jiraTicket, setJiraTicket] = useState([]);
```

This is the fetch function for the API request (${} will be filled with user input):

```
    function getJiraTicket() {
    axios.get(`${username}:${apiToken}@Content-Type:application/json/https:/${jiraSiteName}.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/${projectKey}-${ticketId}`)
        .then((res) => {
            const data = res.data;
            setJiraTicket(data);
        })
}
```

The button inside the react component return should invoke the fetch function:

```
return(
   <Container>
      <Button onClick{getJiraTicket()}>Fetch Jira Ticket</Button>
   </Container>
);
```

This is the error I'm currently getting, because the authorization is not working the way I did it
(I replaced the provided username, API token etc. for this example):

GET http://localhost:3000/username:apitoken@https:/sitename.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/projectkey-ticketid 404 (not found)

**Edit:**

My current approach:

```
    function getJiraTicket() {
    axios.get(`${userName}:${apiToken}@https://${siteName}.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/${projectId}-${ticketId}`,{
        auth: {
            username: userName,
            password: apiToken,
        },
        withCredentials: true
    })
        .then((res) => {
            const data = res.data;
            console.log(data);
            setJiraTicket(data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            // This error means: The request was made and the server responded with a status code
            if(err.res) {
                console.log(err.res.data);
                console.log(err.res.status);
                console.log(err.res.headers);
                console.log("request was made and server responded with status");
            // The request was made but no response was received
            } else if (err.request) {
                console.log(err.request);
                console.log("request was made, but no response was received");
            // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an error
            } else {
                console.log("Error", err.message);
                console.log("request is note set up correctly");
            }
            console.log(err.config);
        })
```

Current error, which I defined accordingly to the axios doc: "request was made, but no response was received"

Endpoint that works well in Postman (Basic auth is provided in Postman):
https://sitename.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/projectid-ticketid

Comment: The error you're getting is not an authorization error, it's a 404 (Look at the URL you're attempting to send)

Comment: Your are trying to send the content type header in the URL . Axios has it's [own header methods](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/axios/headers)

Comment: @Jamie_D I'll take a look at it, thank you

Comment: You are also missing the second forward slash in the  https target.

Comment: Remove `withCredentials` and the credentials from the URL, ie `axios.get(\`https://${siteName}.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/${projectId}-${ticketId}\`, { auth: { username: userName, password: apiToken } })`. You're also missing an `=` after `onClick`

Comment: that also throws a CORS error and I've added the = earlier on, there's no problem with invoking the function, but thanks for the reminder @Phil

Comment: Exactly what CORS error? FYI [Jira Cloud doesn't support CORS access](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRACLOUD-30371), you'll need to use a proxy

Comment: Setting credentials is necessary I think. This is from the Axios doc:  `withCredentials` indicates whether or not cross-site Access-Control requests should be made using credentials. withCredentials is set to false by default

Comment: You aren't using cookie-based authentication so no, you do not need `withCredentials`

Comment: This is the error @Phil Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://XY.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/XY-XY' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: I updated my comment above but just to reiterate, Jira Cloud does not support CORS access

Comment: Saw the issue ticket you've linked.. Axios has a proxy example, maybe that will work:
 proxy: {
    protocol: 'https',
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 9000,
    auth: {
      username: 'mikeymike',
      password: 'rapunz3l'
    }
  },

Answer (score 0):

Update: CORS access isn't allowed, when an application tries to access the Jira API endpoints directly. This restriction takes place in order to prevent random authenticated requests to the specific Jira site, because the access is based on session based authentication. However **the API endpoints can be accessed, if OAuth 2.0 is used** instead of Basic auth, because the application will redirect the user to the Jira auth itself via this link:

> https://auth.atlassian.com/authorize?   audience=api.atlassian.com&
> client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&
> scope=REQUESTED_SCOPE_ONE%20REQUESTED_SCOPE_TWO&
> redirect_uri=https://YOUR_APP_CALLBACK_URL&
> state=YOUR_USER_BOUND_VALUE&   response_type=code&   prompt=consent

Source: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/oauth-2-3lo-apps/#known-issues

Answer (score -1):

Axios uses a headers config for get/post so you should not include them in your URL. Here is a general example of how you should construct the URL and apply headers:

```
let axiosUrl = `https://${jiraSiteName}.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/${projectKey}-${ticketId}`
axios({
    baseURL: axiosUrl,
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"
    },
    //timeout: 2000,
    auth: {
        username: userName,
        password: apiToken,
    }
})
    .then((res) => {
        setJiraTicket(res.data);
    })
     .catch(function (error) {
         console.log(error);
     });
```

Comment: I've been trying a similar approach for quite a while already, but it did not work out unfortunately. I don't have an Authorization problem, as you already mentioned, yet I receive a 404 error while trying to access the endpoint , even though it works great in Postman.

I'll edit my post so you can see my current approach.

Comment: I suppose that the @ is not accepted here between apiToken and https: ${apiToken}@https://$

Comment: I didn't add some of the configuration you have, such as the content type, because axios does that by default (according to the doc).

Comment: Just remove `${userName}:${apiToken}@` since you are already sending the auth credentials in the Auth config

Comment: I will update my answer accordingly ....

Comment: It throws a CORS error, tried it without the auth in URL before:
has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: I updated my answer to send a origin header ... try that and see if it works

Comment: Did not work unfortunately

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-*` are **response** headers that come from the server. They do not belong in your request and in general will more than likely result in errors like _"Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers"_.

Comment: Yep was about to just post a similar comment @Phil, if it's a CORS issue it's likely the hostname hasn't been whitelisted on the JIRA side (although just seen it works fine in Postman)

Comment: Exactly, realized that earlier, when I received Access-Control-Allow-* from the Jira server as a response, while accessing the endpoint with the auth details inside the URL

Comment: I have an API token and don't get a CORS error, when I use my edited approach @Jamie_D. I only get a 404 error, which is probably caused by Jira expecting a different format while entering the auth information in front of the actual endpoint for fetching the data

Comment: @lu_lu so seems you've disabled CORS, so are you still getting the 404?

Comment: @lu_lu 404 would have nothing to do with auth, I'd stab a guess at possibly a wrongly encoded URL segment (either `projectKey` or `ticketId`), try manually hardcoding the URL in your code to rule it out.

Comment: it was a 404 error since the beginning, I only got the CORS error after deleting the auth information from the endpoint URL and I'm still getting a 404 error thrown @James